# DayNight mode declarative set corresponding backgrounds

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to use 2 different images (one for day and one for night) as background for certain views depending on if day or night mode is activated. I know I can do this in code - but is there also a way to do this in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create day/night folders in your resources by adding -night and -notnight (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)).

So you would crete a drawable-night and a drawable-notnight for your night and day backgrounds respectively.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was searching for